# How to run mediapipe face detection codepen.io demo locally on my laptop?

Tags: typescript, localhost, face-detection, codepen, mediapipe

I tried [mediapipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/) [`face detection`](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_detection#javascript-solution-api) demo given at https://codepen.io/mediapipe/pen/dyOzvZM which is working nicely. But I want to run this on my laptop.

I created `index.html` file and copy pasted code from codepen to `index.html`.

1. I copy pasted codepen's `HTMl` code in `<body>` in `<html>`.
2. I copy pasted codepen's `CSS` code in `<style>` in `head`.
3. I copy pasted codepen's `typescript` code's javascript version in `<script type="module">`

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        @keyframes spin {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        .abs {
            position: absolute;
        }

        a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;

            &:hover {
                color: lightblue;
            }
        }

        body {
            bottom: 0;
            font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
            color: white;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            transform-origin: 0px 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .container {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #596e73;
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }

        .input_video {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;

            &.selfie {
                transform: scale(-1, 1);
            }
        }

        .input_image {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .canvas-container {
            display: flex;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .output_canvas {
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .logo {
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 20px;

            .title {
                color: white;
                font-size: 28px;
            }

            .subtitle {
                position: relative;
                color: white;
                font-size: 10px;
                left: -30px;
                top: 20px;
            }
        }

        .control-panel {
            position: absolute;
            left: 10px;
            top: 10px;
        }

        .loading {
            display: flex;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            align-items: center;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            justify-content: center;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 1s;

            .message {
                font-size: x-large;
            }

            .spinner {
                position: absolute;
                width: 120px;
                height: 120px;
                animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
                border: 32px solid #bebebe;
                border-top: 32px solid #3498db;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        }

        .loaded .loading {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .shoutout {
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <video class="input_video"></video>
        <div class="canvas-container">
            <canvas class="output_canvas" width="1280px" height="720px">
            </canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="loading">
            <div class="spinner"></div>
            <div class="message">
                Loading
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="abs logo" href="http://www.mediapipe.dev" target="_blank">
            <div style="display: flex;align-items: center;bottom: 0;right: 10px;">
                <!-- <img class="logo" src="logo_white.png" alt="" style="
                  height: 50px;"> -->
                <span class="title">MediaPipe</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="shoutout">
            <div>
                <a href="https://solutions.mediapipe.dev/face_detection">
                    Click here for more info
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-panel">
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<script type="module">
    import DeviceDetector from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/device-detector-js@2.2.10";
    // Usage: testSupport({client?: string, os?: string}[])
    // Client and os are regular expressions.
    // See: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/device-detector-js@2.2.10/README.md for
    // legal values for client and os
    testSupport([
        { client: 'Chrome' },
    ]);
    function testSupport(supportedDevices) {
        const deviceDetector = new DeviceDetector();
        const detectedDevice = deviceDetector.parse(navigator.userAgent);
        let isSupported = false;
        for (const device of supportedDevices) {
            if (device.client !== undefined) {
                const re = new RegExp(`^${device.client}$`);
                if (!re.test(detectedDevice.client.name)) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (device.os !== undefined) {
                const re = new RegExp(`^${device.os}$`);
                if (!re.test(detectedDevice.os.name)) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            isSupported = true;
            break;
        }
        if (!isSupported) {
            alert(`This demo, running on ${detectedDevice.client.name}/${detectedDevice.os.name}, ` +
                `is not well supported at this time, continue at your own risk.`);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @fileoverview Demonstrates a minimal use case for MediaPipe face tracking.
     */
    const controls = window;
    const drawingUtils = window;
    const mpFaceDetection = window;
    // Our input frames will come from here.
    const videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('input_video')[0];
    const canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName('output_canvas')[0];
    const controlsElement = document.getElementsByClassName('control-panel')[0];
    const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    // We'll add this to our control panel later, but we'll save it here so we can
    // call tick() each time the graph runs.
    const fpsControl = new controls.FPS();
    // Optimization: Turn off animated spinner after its hiding animation is done.
    const spinner = document.querySelector('.loading');
    spinner.ontransitionend = () => {
        spinner.style.display = 'none';
    };
    function onResults(results) {
        // Hide the spinner.
        document.body.classList.add('loaded');
        // Update the frame rate.
        fpsControl.tick();
        // Draw the overlays.
        canvasCtx.save();
        canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
        canvasCtx.drawImage(results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
        if (results.detections.length > 0) {
            drawingUtils.drawRectangle(canvasCtx, results.detections[0].boundingBox, { color: 'blue', lineWidth: 4, fillColor: '#00000000' });
            drawingUtils.drawLandmarks(canvasCtx, results.detections[0].landmarks, {
                color: 'red',
                radius: 5,
            });
        }
        canvasCtx.restore();
    }
    const faceDetection = new mpFaceDetection.FaceDetection({
        locateFile: (file) => {
            return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_detection@0.4/${file}`;
        }
    });
    faceDetection.onResults(onResults);
    // Present a control panel through which the user can manipulate the solution
    // options.
    new controls
        .ControlPanel(controlsElement, {
            selfieMode: true,
            model: 'short',
            minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
        })
        .add([
            new controls.StaticText({ title: 'MediaPipe Face Detection' }),
            fpsControl,
            new controls.Toggle({ title: 'Selfie Mode', field: 'selfieMode' }),
            new controls.SourcePicker({
                onSourceChanged: () => {
                    faceDetection.reset();
                },
                onFrame: async (input, size) => {
                    const aspect = size.height / size.width;
                    let width, height;
                    if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
                        height = window.innerHeight;
                        width = height / aspect;
                    }
                    else {
                        width = window.innerWidth;
                        height = width * aspect;
                    }
                    canvasElement.width = width;
                    canvasElement.height = height;
                    await faceDetection.send({ image: input });
                },
                examples: {
                    images: [],
                    videos: [],
                },
            }),
            new controls.Slider({
                title: 'Model Selection',
                field: 'model',
                discrete: { 'short': 'Short-Range', 'full': 'Full-Range' },
            }),
            new controls.Slider({
                title: 'Min Detection Confidence',
                field: 'minDetectionConfidence',
                range: [0, 1],
                step: 0.01
            }),
        ])
        .on(x => {
            const options = x;
            videoElement.classList.toggle('selfie', options.selfieMode);
            faceDetection.setOptions(options);
        });

</script>
```

I served this index.html using `python3 -m http.server` so I can access it from `http://localhost:8000`.
When I run this code on Chrome browser I see no errors in devtool console

How can I make https://codepen.io/mediapipe/pen/dyOzvZM demo code working on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following links to the `head`:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils@0.6/control_utils.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/camera_utils@0.3/camera_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils@0.6/control_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/drawing_utils@0.3/drawing_utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_detection/face_detection.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

or save the files locally...